Gradle sub project dependency inheritance
I have a gradle multi project setup. Let’s say the project contains two sub projects
sample
|_project1
| |_build.gradle.kts
|_project2
| |_build.gradle.kts
|_settings.gradle.kts
|_build.gradle.kts


settings.gradle.kts includes both project1 and project2
projects2 has following dependency specification
dependencies {
implementation(“org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.0”)
}

project1 has the following dependency specification
dependencies {
implementation(project(“:project2”)) // Dependency on project2
}

I could not use/access postgres jdbc driver classes in project1’s classes directly.
dependency graph of project1 show postgres driver jar only in
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set ‘main’.
-– project :project2
-– org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.0
-– org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.31.0


The compile classpath of project1 appears as
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set ‘main’.
-– project :project2
Is this the default behaviour? Should project1 dependency be modified to include postgres jdbc?

Yes, it's the default behaviour.
If, in a project P:

A dependency D is declared in the implementation configuration, D is available within P, but not to consumers of P.
A dependency D is declared in the api configuration, D is available within P and to consumers of P.

Which one you use depends on how you want to design your application.
The api configuration is provided by the Java Library plugin and further details are set out in its documentation.
